# sql query want to list employeeId,EmployeeName,ManagerId,ManagerName,TopManagerId,TopManagerName

Tags: sql

output like

```
EmpId,EmpName,ManagerId,ManagerName,TopManagerId,TopManagerName
```

Employee Table has 3 columns

```
EmpId,EmpName,ManagerId
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle, they are different, Please dont just SPAM as many tags as you can find

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) 
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are we supposed to guess where `ManagerName,TopManagerId,TopManagerName` are going to come from? Please remember, we know only what you tell us about your problem, we are not clairvoyant and we are not looking over your shoulder

Comment: Please would you read, [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)
and amend your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT empid,
       empname,
       managerid,
       PRIOR empname AS managername,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT Empid AS topmanagerid,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT empname AS topmanagername
FROM   table_name
START WITH managerid IS NULL
CONNECT BY PRIOR empid = managerid
ORDER SIBLINGS BY EmpName
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (EmpId,EmpName,ManagerId) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice', NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Betty', 1    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carol', 2    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Debra', 3    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Emily', 2    FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | EMPID | EMPNAME | MANAGERID | MANAGERNAME | TOPMANAGERID | TOPMANAGERNAME |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | Alice | *null* | *null* | 1 | Alice |
> | 2 | Betty | 1 | Alice | 1 | Alice |
> | 3 | Carol | 2 | Betty | 1 | Alice |
> | 4 | Debra | 3 | Carol | 1 | Alice |
> | 5 | Emily | 2 | Betty | 1 | Alice |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/BmUMc3JH)*

Comment: thanks for your support and it's working fine in Oracle. But I'm looking for the solution in SQL server. Please help

Comment: @JitheshKRamesh Then why did you tag the question with MySQL and Oracle if you were looking for an SQL Server solution? You should tag it with SQL Server and not add unnecessary tags.

Comment: I though we can convert and it will work. But unfortunately, it didn't convert.